# DDL error in Create table statement of Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting "Cannot set destination table in jobs with DDL statements" error while creating a table in Big Query. How to resolve this?

```sql
create table `decent-fulcrum-254016.4thOct_LR.NewData_Train` 
as 
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM `decent-fulcrum-254016.4thOct_LR.NewData` 
  order by rand() LIMIT 700000
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are running this DDL in BigQuery UI - make sure you don't have destination table set - check Options panel

Same recommendation if you run it via API, or any other client - make sure you don't set destination table!

Comment: 2021. It is in More > Query Settings > Destination > Save query results in a temporary table